.NET 7.0 and SuiteTalk not communicating
I have an application using TBA to connected to a NetSuite instance via SuiteTalk. Have gen'd the Consumer ID's and Token ID's, consumed the "https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2024_1_0/netsuite.wsdl" but when I attempt ANY SuiteTalk call I get a "405 Method Not Allowed". I have a .Net Framework 4.8 application using the same ID's working fine. Any one able to get this working in any .Net Core version?
strURL = "https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2024_1_0/netsuite.wsdl";

EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(strURL);
NetSuitePortTypeClient wcfClientNetSuite = new NetSuitePortTypeClient(myBindingNetSuite, myEndpoint);
getDataCenterUrlsResponse DCUrlsResp = new getDataCenterUrlsResponse();
wcfClientNetSuite.getDataCenterUrls(
                        null, 
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        NetSuiteAcct,
                        out DCUrlsResult
                    );

https://123456.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2017_2_0/netsuite.wsdl

The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageHelper.ValidateResponseStatusCode()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageHelper.d__7.MoveNext()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.<ReceiveReplyAsync>d__18.MoveNext() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.<RequestAsync>d__33.MoveNext() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.<RequestAsyncInternal>d__32.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletionNoSpin[TResult](Task1 task)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(MethodCall methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args)
at generatedProxy_2.getDataCenterUrls(getDataCenterUrlsRequest )
at NetSuiteServiceWcfSvc.NetSuitePortTypeClient.NetSuiteServiceWcfSvc.NetSuitePortType.getDataCenterUrls(getDataCenterUrlsRequest request) in C:\Users\csale\source\repos\HRDEFCOMPTRACK\frmHRDefComp\Connected Services\NetSuiteServiceWcfSvc\Reference.cs:line 412753
at NetSuiteServiceWcfSvc.NetSuitePortTypeClient.getDataCenterUrls(TokenPassport tokenPassport, ApplicationInfo applicationInfo, PartnerInfo partnerInfo, Preferences preferences, String account, GetDataCenterUrlsResult& getDataCenterUrlsResult) in C:\Users\csale\source\repos\HRDEFCOMPTRACK\frmHRDefComp\Connected Services\NetSuiteServiceWcfSvc\Reference.cs:line 412764
at DefCompTrack.ViewModels.DefCompTranxViewModel.LoadNetSuitePayrollTranx() in C:\Users\csale\source\repos\HRDEFCOMPTRACK\frmHRDefComp\ViewModels\DefCompTranxViewModel.cs:line 869

First of all, the cause of a 405 error is usually an incorrect HTTP request method. Since you don't provide a service code, I have the following guess: Your client should call the service via a Get request. This uses the webget attribute in .NET Framework 4.8. But this attribute is not available in .NET 7. You must have corewcf.webhttp installed to use it.

Thank you for your response. I had already included the CoreWcf.Http package but not the CoreWcf.Webhttp package. I loaded the package but still getting the same 405. Might not be clear on how to use. Still researching.

I researched the relevant information and found out the cause of the problem.
Upgrade to .NET Core Url attribute has disappeared.
Endpoints for SuiteTalk are now account-specific. A few years ago, everyone called https://webservices.netsuite.com. Then, the data center (Na1, Na2, etc.) is added somewhere. Now, the endpoint looks like this:
https://123456.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com
The 123456 is replaced with your account ID.
The document tells you to point to the WSDL at https://webservices.netsuite.com and then call getDataCenterUrls to get the actual endpoint set using the Url property on NetSuiteService. Unfortunately, NetSuitePortTypeClient does not contain a Url
attribute.
This is the document.

I did see the Ben Mills document and did follow his pattern of the account based end point and have tried many iterations of various versions of the wsdl but still get the same 405. I added the last wsdl url I used and it's stack trace. What i'm also unclear about is the url used  to consume the web service vs the url used to call the web service. I would assume that you would consume the same version that you would use for your endpoint but since there is little to know docs on .Net Core usage I can only guess and experiment.

Can you provide the code and configuration file for the following program.cs? I suspect it has something to do with this, but nothing to test.

The only "program.cs" I have is for another SOAP web service that I am hosting. Or are you requesting something else?

You can try installing the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors package to handle cross-origin requests. And then you add the code to Program.cs: app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");.

It appears that package has been depricated but i do see the "Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" package available. I might not be following fully, but I don't have access to the "Program.cs" with the SuiteTalk web service which I assume you're suggesting this line be placed.

Endpoint.Address: Some users have reported that this method does not work. You try to generate the endpoint manually.

I can try. I did however had to move on from the .Net7.0 & SuiteTalk by creating a .Net 4.8 console app to handle the SuiteTalk interaction. I'll make an attempt at creating the endpoint again. I did look at this earlier and stumbled on something but can't remember.
